# Abrir un Fpdf en una Ventana Modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, base-de-datos, vue.js

Soy casi nuevo en esto, estoy en practicas profesionales para terminar mi tecnico
Tengo una ruta para mi fpdf que se encuenta en un controlador lo tengo en rutado por parametro`Route::get('ticket/{folio}',[//ruta para generar un ticket 'as'=>'ticket', 'uses'=>'VentaController@ticket' ]);`
si lo llama me trae el pdf este es el codigo del fpdf`public function ticket($folio){
$venta= Venta::find($folio);
$altura = 100;

```
   //Definimos el tamaño del ticket
   $pdf = new Fpdf('P', 'mm', array(58,$altura ));

   $pdf->AddPage();

  $pdf->SetMargins(3,2,3);
   $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 6);
   $pdf->Cell(40,3,'ABARROTES LA LUPITA',0,1,'C');
   $pdf->Cell(8,3, 'FOLIO:', 0,0,'L');
   $pdf->Cell(20,3, $venta->folio,0,0,'L');
   $pdf->Cell(10,3, 'FECHA:',0,0,'L');
   $pdf->Cell(10,3, $venta->fecha_venta, 0,1,'L');
   $pdf->Cell(40,1,'','B','C');
   $pdf->Ln(2);

   $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 5);
   $pdf->Cell(5,3, 'SKU',1,0,'C');
   $pdf->Cell(25,3, 'PRODUTO',1,0,'C');
   $pdf->Cell(8,3, 'CANT',1,0,'C');
   $pdf->Cell(5,3, 'P.U',1,0,'C');
   $pdf->Cell(8,3,'TOTAL',1,1,'C');

   $detalles=$venta->detalles;

   foreach ($detalles as $detalle) {
        $pdf->Cell(5,3,$detalle->sku,0,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(25,3,$detalle->productos->nombre,0,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(8,3,$detalle->cantidad,0,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(5,3,$detalle->precio,0,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(8,3,$detalle->total,0,1,'C');
   }

   $pdf->OutPut();
   exit;
}`
```

[image: fpdf funcionando segun el folio de la venta]

mi problema es que desconosco de como meter el fpdf que se crea al momento y no esta guardado en ninguna parte de internet

cuando le doy imprimir me debe abrir la ventana modal con el pdf pero solo me abre la venta modal
[image: solo me muestra la ventana modal]

esto es todo mi codigo
ventas.blade.php

```js
function init() {

var apiProducto=ruta + '/apiProducto'; //se crea para tener un acceso global. 
var apiVenta=ruta + '/apiVenta';

new Vue({
    //Asignamos el token
    http: {
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('value')
            }
        },

    //Especificar la zona de actuación de Vue
    el:"#apiVenta",

    //Esta sección de VUE sirve para declarar Variables
    //Y constantes. g
    data:{
        //mensaje: 'HOLA MUNDO DESDE LA UTC',
        sku:'',
        ventas:[],
        
        productos:[],
        cantidades:[],
        cant:1,
        auxSubTotal:0,
        pagara_con:0,
        folio:'',
        buscar:'',
        propina:0,
        propina3:0,
        porcentaje:0,




        
    },

    created:function(){
        this.foliar();
        this.obtenerProductos();
    },

    //INICIO DE METHODS
    methods:{
        obtenerProductos:function(){
            
            this.$http.get(apiProducto).then(function(json){
                this.productos=json.data;
                console.log(json.data);
            }).catch(function(json){
                console.log(json);
            });
        },


        buscarProducto:function(){
            var encontrado=0;

            if(this.sku){//INICIO DE IF(THIS.SKU)
    
            var producto = {};

            //Rutina de busqueda

            for (var i = 0; i < this.ventas.length; i++) {

                if (this.sku===this.ventas[i].sku){

                    encontrado=1;
                    this.ventas[i].cantidad++;
                    this.cantidades[i]++;
                    this.sku='';
                    break;
                } //this.ventas[1];

            }//fin de rutina de busqueda

            //Inicio GET de ARRAY
            //var producto = {}
            if (encontrado===0) 
            this.$http.get(apiProducto + '/' + this.sku).then(function(j){
                console.log(j.data);

                producto = {
                    sku:j.data.sku,
                    nombre:j.data.nombre,
                    precio:j.data.precio,
                    cantidad:1, 
                    total:j.data.precio,
                    foto:'prods/' + j.data.foto,
                };

    
                    this.ventas.push(producto);
                    this.cantidades.push(1);
                this.sku='';
            });

        }//FIN DE IF(THIS.SKU)

        },//fin de buscar producto


        eliminarProducto:function(id){
            this.ventas.splice(id,1); //Splice es eliminar la mascota
        },

        mostrarCobro:function(){
            $('#modalCobro').modal('show');
        },
        mostrarProducto:function(){
            $('#modalProducto').modal('show');
        },
        mostrarticket(){

            $('#modalticket').modal('show');
        },
        

        foliar:function(){
            //this.folio="VNT-" + moment().format('YYYYMMD8HMMS');
            this.folio=moment().format('YYYYMMD8HMMS');


        },
        
    
        vender:function(){
            var unaVenta = {};
            var deta = [];

            //Preparamos un JSON con los detalles 
            for (var i = 0; i < this.ventas.length; i++) {
            deta.push(
                    {   sku:this.ventas[i].sku,
                        folio:this.folio,
                        cantidad:this.ventas[i].cantidad,
                        precio:this.ventas[i].precio,
                        total:this.ventas[i].total
                    }
                    );
            }


            //Find a JSON Detalles
            unaVenta = {
                folio:this.folio,
                fecha_venta:moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                num_articulos:this.noArticulos,
                subtotal:this.subTotal,
                iva:this.iva,
                total:this.granTotal,
                detalles:deta
            };
            //console.log(unaVenta);
            this.$http.post(apiVenta,unaVenta).then(function(j){
                console.log(j);
                $('#modalCobro').modal('hide');
                this.foliar();
                this.ventas=[];
                this.cantidades=[];
            });
        },
},
//FIN DE METHODS

//SECCION PARA CALCULAR UN VALOR
computed:{
    totalProducto(){
        return (id)=>{
            var total = 0;
                total=this.ventas[id].precio*this.cantidades[id];

            //ACTUALIZO EL TOTAL DEL PRODUCTIO EN EL ARRAY VENTAS
            this.ventas[id].total=total;

            //ACTUALIZO LA CANTIDAD EN EL ARRAY VENTAS
            this.ventas[id].cantidad=this.cantidades[id];

            return total.toFixed(1);//Regresa ek total con un decimal

        }
    },//FIN DE TOTALPRODUCTO

    subTotal(){
        var total=0;

        //Se recorre del ultimo hacia abajo
        for (var i = this.ventas.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            total=total+this.ventas[i].total;
        }

        //Mando una copia del subtotal a la seccion del data 
        //Para el uso de otros calculos
        this.auxSubTotal=total.toFixed(1);
        return total.toFixed(1);
    },//FIN DEL SUBTOTAL

    iva(){
        var auxIva=0;

        auxIva = this.auxSubTotal*0.16;
        return auxIva.toFixed(1);
    },
        

    granTotal(){
        
        var auxTotal=0;
        

        auxTotal=this.auxSubTotal*1.16;
        //linea 212 cuando la activo dice
        //toFixed no es una funcion 
        //auxTotal=auxTotal+this.propina2;
        auxTotal=auxTotal.toFixed(1);
        return auxTotal;
    },
    propina2(){
        var prop2=0;
        //propina por porcentaje
        var porcentaje2=0;
        //propina directo
        var directo=0;
        //se agarra el porcentaje de la vista
        porcentaje2=this.porcentaje / 100;
        prop2=(this.auxSubTotal*1.16)*porcentaje2;
        directo=prop2+this.propina;
        //Mando una copia del subtotal a la seccion del data 
        //Para el uso de otros calculos
        this.propina3=prop2.toFixed(1);
        return directo.toFixed(1);
        
    },
    
    noArticulos(){
        var acum=0;
        for (var i = this.ventas.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            acum=acum+this.ventas[i].cantidad;
        }
        return acum;
    },

    cambio(){
        var camb=0;
        camb=this.pagara_con - this.granTotal;
        camb=camb.toFixed();

        return camb;

    },
    filtroProducto:function(){
            return this.productos.filter((sku)=>{
                return sku.nombre.toLowerCase().match(this.buscar.toLowerCase().trim()) 

            });
        }
    
},


}) 
} window.onload = init;
```

```html
<div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" @click="mostrarCobro">Cobrar </button>
                    </div>
            
            <!-- Modal para el formulario del registro de los moovimientos -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalCobro" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Asistente de cobro</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>A PAGAR :</label>    
                </div> 
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" disabled :value="granTotal">
                </div>
            </div><br>

            <div class="form-wor">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>PAGA CON:</label>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="pagara_con">
                </div><br>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label>SU CAMBIO ES: </label>       
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" disabled :value="cambio"> 
                    </div>  
                </div>
                
            </div> 
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="vender()">Guardar</button>
       <!--/* <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="ticket/2022042289043" class="nav-link active">
                  <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>imprimir ticket</p>
                </a>
              </li>*/-->
              <div class="input-group-append">
                         <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" @click="mostrarticket()">imprimir ticket</button>
                    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- aqui termina el modal-->
```

Comment: Un documento PDF no se puede integrar dentro de una página, pero puedes intentar con un `<iframe src="ruta/archivo.pdf"></iframe>` dentro del modal. Referencia: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: si muchas gracias si me funciono